# entity not recognizing in Google dialogflow

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have created **mobile_storage** entity as below.
[image]

and created intent as below.

[image]

But while parsing for the below query, it is not recognizing storage correctly.

[image]

What could be the issue? 
Is there any way to capture the storage data more efficiently?
Is there any issue in entity which I created?

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to successfully extract the values from the created entity.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It is a developer entity, but what is the issue here?

Comment: Please add the screenshot of storage entity.